# How can a moderately sized memory allocation fail in a 64 bit process on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, 64-bit, memory-management, nsdata

I'm building a photo book layout application. The application frequently decompresses JPEG images into in-memory bitmap buffers. The size of the images is constrained to 100 megapixels (while they usually do not exceed 15 megapixels).

Sometimes memory allocations for these buffers fail: `[[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:]` returns `nil`. This seems to happen in situations where the systems's free physical memory approaches zero.

My understanding of the [virtual memory system in Mac OS X](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/AboutMemory.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001880-BCICIHAB) was that an allocation in a 64 bit process *virtually* (sic) can't fail. There are 16 exabyte of address space of which I'm trying to allocate a maximum of 400 megabytes at a time. Theoretically I could allocate 40 billion of these buffers without hitting the hard limit of the available address space. Of course practical limits would prevent this scenario as swap space is constrained by the boot volume's size. In reality I'm only making very few of these allocations (less than ten).

What I do not understand is the fact that an allocation fails, no matter how low physical memory is at that point. I thought that—as long as there's swap space left—memory allocation would not fail (as the pages are not even mapped at this point).

The application is garbage collected.

**Edit:**

I had time to dig into this problem a little further and here are my findings:

1. The problem only occurs in a garbage collected process.
2. When the allocation from `NSMutableData` fails, a plain `malloc` still succeeds to allocate the same amount of memory.
3. The error always happens when overall physical memory approaches zero (swapping is about to take place).

I assume `NSData` uses `NSAllocateCollectable` to perform the allocation instead of `malloc` when running under garbage collection.

My conclusion from all that is that the collector is unable to allocate big chunks of memory when physical memory is low. Which again, I don't understand.

Comment: Are you running the OS as 64-bit? One can run a 64-bit process, but I don't think you get the full benefits of 64-bit unless the OS is also running in 64-bit mode. I think that may make a difference in your case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer lies in the implementation of [libauto](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/libauto/).

As of OS X 10.6 an arena of 8 Gb is allocated for garbage collected memory on 64-bit platforms. This arena is cut in half for large allocations (>=128k) and small (<2048b) or medium (<128k) allocations.

So in effect on 10.6 you have 4Gb of memory available for large allocations of garbage collected memory. On 10.5 the arena had a size of [32Gb](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/libauto/libauto-77.1/AutoConfiguration.h), but Apple lowered that size to 8Gb on [10.6](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2009/Dec/msg00131.html).

Answer (score 1):

Another guess, but it may be that your colleague's machine is configured with a stricter maximum memory per user process setting. To check, type

`ulimit -a`

Into a console. For me, I get:

```
~ iainmcgin$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 256
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 266
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

From my settings above, it seems there is no per-process limit on memory usage. This may not be the case for your colleague, for some reason.

I'm using Snow Leopard:

```
~ iainmcgin$ uname -rs
Darwin 10.6.0
```

Comment: Good idea, thank you, but it does not seem to be the source of the described problem. I was since able to reproduce the bug on a couple of machines, mine included, and there's no custom limit for vmem.

Answer (score 0):

Even though a 64 bit computer can theoretically address 18 EB, current processors are limited to 256 TB. Of course, you aren't reaching this limit either. But the amount of memory your process can use at one time is limited to the amount of RAM available. The OS may also limit the amount of RAM you can use. According to the link you posted, "Even for computers that have 4 or more gigabytes of RAM available, the system rarely dedicates this much RAM to a single process."

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the restricted address space. A small command line test shows that a 64 bit process in Mac OS X can allocate a maximum of 128 TB. But as you say, my process does not hit this limit. Regarding the rest of you answer: An allocation does not *use any memory*, it rather reserves pages. Only after *mapping* these pages (by reading or writing them), physical memory is consumed. So the allocation itself should not fail (on Mac OS which in contrary to iOS can swap memory out).

Comment: @Nikolai The allocation could fail if the OS limits the number of pages it will let the application use at a time, so if you try to allocate a lot of memory before other memory has a chance to be paged out, it could decide not to let you.

Comment: Do you know that the operating system decides allocation failures based on available physical pages? Do you have a source for this?

Comment: I haven't seen anything saying it does, but it is a possibility, and if you try to use more memory than RAM before anything gets paged out, there is nowhere to put it.

Comment: I'd assume the allocation would block in this case. Or maybe the mapping of the pages (when accessed) would just take longer when swapping is needed (this seems more likely). But all this is only speculation.

Comment: It would be nice if you could explain this limitation a bit more in detail. See my related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47595127/what-are-the-limitations-with-malloc-on-a-64-bit-process-on-macos

Answer (score 0):

You may be running out of swap space. Even though you have a swap file and virtual memory, the amount of swap space available is still limited by the space on your hard disk for swap files.

Comment: Good point, but at the time the error occurred on my machine, the startup volume had 120GB of free space left.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a memory fragmentation issue. Perhaps there are not any single contiguous chunks of 400 MB available at the time of allocation?

You could try to allocate these large chunks at the very start of your application's life cycle, before the heap gets a chance to become fragmented by numerous smaller allocations.

Comment: Fragmentation is a good idea–but it seems in this case the source of the problem is elsewhere (since malloc still works, see my answer).

Answer (score -1):

`initWithBytes:length:` tries to allocate its entire length in active memory, essentially equivalent to `malloc()` of that size. If the length exceeds available memory, you will get nil. If you want to use large files with `NSData`, I'd recommend `initWithContentsOfMappedFile:` or similar initializers, as they use the VM system to pull parts of the file in and out of active memory when needed.

Comment: As I tried to make clear in the question, I'm using the buffers for **decompressed** images, so mapping files is not an option. Regarding your statement: "If the length exceeds available memory, you will get nil.": This is exactly what the question was about. My understanding of virtual memory (in conjunction with swap space) is that as long as the address space is not filled up no allocation should fail.

Comment: Quite right, sorry about that. In my (limited) testing `NSData` never had a problem allocating many gigabytes of memory in a 64-bit process. It does have a 2GB limited in 32-bit machines. In any case, because NSData is an object, it has to live in the Objective-C runtime, which allocates all objects on the heap. For very large allocations you may want to use the `CFData` functions, as they don't incur that overhead and allows you to use Mach's Copy-On-Write memory management. You can also check his system logs to see if the allocation failure logged an exception like it should.